# How can I access the size of a Compute Shader's local work group from the CPU?

Tags: c++, opengl, compute-shader

Given a compute shader where I have set the local size of each dimension to the values x, y and z, is there any way for me to access that information from the c++ code? ie,

```
//Pseudo Code c++
int size[3]
x = get local sizes from linked compute shader
print(x);

//GLSL Code
layout (local_size_x = a number, local_size_y = a number, local_size_z = a number) in;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having run around looking, I found the following on Khronos.org, on its page concerning `glGetProgramiv`, found here:

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3/html/glGetProgramiv.xhtml

> GL_COMPUTE_WORK_GROUP_SIZE
>   params returns an array of three integers containing the local work group size of the compute program as specified by its input layout qualifier(s). program must be the name of a program object that has been previously linked successfully and contains a binary for the compute shader stage.

This makes the line I needed

`glGetProgramiv(ComputeShaderID, GL_COMPUTE_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, localWorkGroupSize);`

where `localWorkGroupSize` is an array of 3 integers.