How get Vulkan compute shader local_size (work group size) op CPU?
I have Vulkan compute shader in HSLS language. In the beginning I set local_size (work group size) as:
layout (local_size_x = 32, local_size_y = 32, local_size_z = 1) in;
So there are 32x32=1024 threads in my work group. Then I need to dispatch the shader with size grid size. For example to process 2048x1024 image by this shader I need grid size of 64x32. At present I have to hard code local_size both in shader GLSL code (to run) and in C++ code (to calc grid size). Which is not quite error-prone. How could I get local_size from shader module / pipeline?
I have found vkGetShaderInfoAMD function, but it just crashes on nVidia card. Also AMD in its name it not very promising.

Generally speaking, as already described in the answer you got, VUlkan doesn't provide mechanisms to get back the information you already sent to the API. The application (in the meaning given by the Vulkan specs) is expected to keep all information it needs outside Vulkan.
This enabled simplifications in driver work, because unlike OpenGL it doesn't have to keep trace of everything because it may be useful. Hence, there's no utter nonsense akin to glGetShaderSource  that's available in Vulkan. And this is consistent with the design goals of the API.

Regarding your problem, you may want to check things like SPIRV-Reflect, which does what you think it does.

You handed Vulkan a SPIR-V shader that included the SPIR-V equivalent of a local_size declaration. As such, you technically know what that shader's local_size is. And, broadly speaking, Vulkan as an API is not in the business of giving you information which you already gave to Vulkan.
If you need to learn something about a piece of SPIR-V code, you'll have to parse it yourself. Or, more likely, use a SPIR-V parsing/introspection library.
Note that even the VK_AMD_shader_info extension is not about querying the kind of information you could figure out just by looking at the SPIR-V. It's for querying platform-specific information about the post-compilation code, which you would be unable to know about otherwise.

Actually the question was how to make SpirV and C++ parts consistent. Like one do in Cuda. At the end I really have done automatic parsing during shader compilation. It is pitty tah Vulkan cannot handle this. Even OpenGL can for compute shaders.

Like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45416505/how-can-i-access-the-size-of-a-compute-shaders-local-work-group-from-the-cpu

Right. As I said, Vulkan is not in the business of giving you information you gave to it. The SPIR-V contains that information, and you gave Vulkan that SPIR-V code, so you had an opportunity to look at the SPIR-V and extract it.
